# Would wood turn into charcoal faster if it is burned in a pressurized environment?

Tags: pyrolysis

It is very easy to make charcoal from firewood and there are many tutorials about this online. However they all state that the process of turning firewood into charcoal can take atleast 3 to 4 hours. That is quite a long time.

I was wondering whether this time span could be shortened by making the charcoal inside a pressurized container like a pressure cooker instead. A pressure cooker cooks food [about 30 percent faster](https://www.finecooking.com/article/the-science-of-pressure-cookers) than conventional methods like steaming, boiling, and braising. So maybe a pressure cooker can also produce charcoal 30 percent faster. Pressure cookers also use 50 to 75 percent less energy due to shorter cooking times.

So would using something like a pressure cooker turn wood into charcoal faster?

Comment: If wood had higher temperature when pressurised at otherwise similar conditions, it would form charcoal faster. But it should not be pressurised air, it would burn brighter.

Comment: @Poutnik Do you think it would also produce better quality charcoal with a higher energy content? I'm assuming that would also be the case because the wood would be exposed to only a limited amount of air while inside the container. But correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: In case of the cooker, pressure serves to increase boiling point. Effect of pressure in charcoal case is unclear. It needs just right amount of air being provided to support the process but not to burn wood.  Another option would be external heating.

Comment: Charcoal doesn't form when wood *burns*: it forms when wood is heated in a low oxygen environment (conventional methods pack wood so that the outer wood burns to provide heat while restricting the oxygen available so the inner wood creates charcoal). So, if you could recreate those conditions, it might work but a pressure cooker might not be the best way. Perhaps a vacuum chamber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increased pressure will increase the rate at which wood burns, probably due to the increased concentration of oxygen.  Li, He, Zhang and Wang compared the rate at which wood burns at high and low altitude [1], and found that "...for the same burning surface area, the burning rate, radiation heat flux and flame temperature at the high altitude was lower than those at the low altitude."

****However, as pointed out by @matt_black, this won't work for charcoal production, since it requires a slow burn in a low-oxygen environment.****  This is needed to remove the water and the volatiles, so that the wood undergoes pyrolysis to form charcoal, instead of combustion to form ash.

Additionally, note the reason a pressure cooker increases cooking rate is entirely different from the reason wood burns faster at increased pressure.  A pressure cooker is for food that is immersed in water.   The temperature of water is limited by its boiling point, which is higher within the higher pressure of a pressure cooker.

[1] Zhen-hua Li, Yaping He, Hui Zhang, Jian Wang.  Combustion characteristics of n-heptane and wood crib fires at different altitudes.  *Proceedings of the Combustion Institute*, Volume 32, Issue 2, 2009, Pages 2481-2488, ISSN 1540-7489, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.proci.2008.06.033.

Comment: Wood burning doesn't create charcoal. Heating wood in a low oxygen environment does. So I don't think this would work.

Comment: @matt_black  Thanks!  I'll update my answer based on this.